# Best way to connect to a private redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection, amazon-redshift, private

I am trying to optimize my Redshift cluster for security, so I set 'publicly accessible' to 'no', however after this I was unable to query off of it or upload to it.  I have the security group set to allow connections from my IP, but still nothing.  I have looked into using an EC2 instance as a bastion host, however I have been unable to sort out how to do that.  Does anyone know the best way to connect to a private cluster or have any suggestions?

Comment: For tips on using a Bastion, search for "port forwarding". Basically, you can SSH into the Bastion with a few extra command options and then it will appear that Redshift is attached to your local computer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you've created your cluster in a VPC, in private subnets.

You have a couple of options for getting access.

Option one is to set up a bastion server.  This has to be in a public subnet (the difference between a public subnet and a private subnet is that the routing table for the public subnet has a target for an internet gateway).  Further, you would need to make sure that the redshift cluster grants access to the bastion server.

Option two would be to set up direct access to your VPC - either by creating a VPN, or setting up Direct Connect.  These would be more complex, but wouldn't need a bastion server.